# Submit button in a header fails to submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

i'm developing a jquery mobile app. In the app there is a form which the user has to submit and i've placed the submit button in the right side in the header. when the user is done with filling of the form and taps on the submit button with a class of `"ui-btn-right"`, it fails to submit.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.ui-btn-right').on('click', function(event) {
      $("#form1").on('submit',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        data = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "register.php",
          data: data
        }).success(function() {
          $("input[type=text]").val("");
        });
      });
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<a href='#' class='ui-btn-right' id="button" >Register</a>
```

Comment: Do you receive any error messages in your dev tools?

Comment: Would be good see you HTML structure. I dont understand why the submit event is inside the click event. Surely the user is submitted the form so the click even is not needed

Comment: Question; does clicking the button work the _second_ time you click it?

Comment: Does it work when you click it twice?

Comment: Please show the HTML. For all we know, the submit button may not be in the form.

Comment: @dwreck08 i dont recieve any error messages

Comment: @chrisForrence when i click many times, nothing happens

Comment: Ok so it's not even a button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just taking a guess here, as we can't see your markup. But it looks like you're not actually submitting the form when you click the button, you're just wiring up the submit event. Try this?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.ui-btn-right').on('click', function(event) {
      $('#form1').submit();
    });
  
  $("#form1").on('submit',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    data = $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "register.php",
      data: data
    }).success(function() {
      $("input[type=text]").val("");
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: This moves the binding of the form submission outside of the button click, which binds the event unnecessarily on load, slowing down the page, instead of when it's definitely going to be used. OP had it in the correct place, and only a very small change was required.

Comment: Again, it's assumptions without seeing the markup. You're assuming that the button in question is the only way to submit the form. My answer allows the form to be submitted if there are other ways outside of the button. Markup would have helped here...

Comment: Quite agree, I don't know why I went against what I usually moan about when people using on click of a button instead of on submit of a form.

Answer (score 2):

Try this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

      $("#form1").on('submit',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        data = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "register.php",
          data: data
        }).success(function() {
          $("input[type=text]").val("");
        });
      });

    $('.ui-btn-right').on('click', function(event) {
        $("#form1").submit(event);
    });
});
```

Comment: That said, it probably makes more sense to put your code inside the .ui-btn-right onclick event handler...

Answer (score 0):

If your button is not in the form and you want to fired the submit event you have to do something like:

```
$('.ui-btn-right').on('click', function(event) {
  $("#form1").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    stuff();
  });
});
```

Comment: How is this any different to how the problem code is now?

Comment: He doesn't trigger the submit event.

Answer (score 0):

Probably I need more data to give answer,but we can go this way.

```
$('.ui-btn-right').on('click', function(event) {
   check here any alert/console message is working
}
```

now you have create `$("#form1").on('submit`

but to submit it you need to do

```
$("#form1").submit();
```

manually as I assume this button is outside of your form.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you provide a cohert answer, formatted correctly it is more likely to be useful.